# how to capture image and save in folder

Tags: android

This is my code which takes an image and saves it in the phone image directory. How do I modify this code to create a new folder in memory and save the captured images there, and also show all images in the main screen. I followed [this guide](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/).

```
package makemachine.android.examples;

import java.io.File;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class PhotoCaptureExample extends Activity 
{
protected Button _button;
protected ImageView _image;
protected TextView _field;
protected String _path;
protected boolean _taken;

protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN   = "photo_taken";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    _image = ( ImageView ) findViewById( R.id.image );
    _field = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.field );
    _button = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.button );
    _button.setOnClickListener( new ButtonClickHandler() );

    _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images 
  /make_machine_example.jpg";
}

public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener 
{
    public void onClick( View view ){
        Log.i("MakeMachine", "ButtonClickHandler.onClick()" );
        startCameraActivity();
    }
}

protected void startCameraActivity()
{
    Log.i("MakeMachine", "startCameraActivity()" );
    File file = new File( _path );
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );

    startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{   
    Log.i( "MakeMachine", "resultCode: " + resultCode );
    switch( resultCode )
    {
        case 0:
            Log.i( "MakeMachine", "User cancelled" );
            break;

        case -1:
            onPhotoTaken();
            break;
    }
}

protected void onPhotoTaken()
{
    Log.i( "MakeMachine", "onPhotoTaken" );

    _taken = true;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( _path, options );

    _image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    _field.setVisibility( View.GONE );
}

@Override 
protected void onRestoreInstanceState( Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Log.i( "MakeMachine", "onRestoreInstanceState()");
    if( savedInstanceState.getBoolean( PhotoCaptureExample.PHOTO_TAKEN ) ) {
        onPhotoTaken();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState ) {
    outState.putBoolean( PhotoCaptureExample.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey create a special directory as you wish in ExternalStorage and save all your files to that folder. Retrieve all the files from that folder and display them in Listview or Gridview. Better you generate file name with currentTimeInMillis() as you want to display many images but use the same directory.

```
_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images 
  /make_machine_example.jpg";
```

instead of above line use below line

```
_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images 
  /"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
```

Adding code for creating directory:

```
File dir = new File("path/to/your/directory");
try{
  if(dir.mkDir()) {
     System.out.println("Directory created");
  } else {
     System.out.println("Directory is not created");
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStacktrace();
}
```

don't forget to add permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: no  i down wana browse my PHone Gallery for save images i wanna create new folder for this application and save there capture images

Comment: help me plz how i create new folder in ph directory and save images there

Comment: hey what do you mean by create directory? instead of taking images in the path take any name which creates a directory.

Comment: i mean i wanna create new folder"Myfolder" in phone memory and save all captured images on that folder

Comment: i did like this but is not create new folder inmemory and save iamges on that folder is save images inphone image gellry  

 _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Myfolder/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";

Comment: @SmartGuy the folder will be created when you give the path, no need of doing it manually. check you sdcard contents in file browser. you will have images folder and the images you took

Comment: @SmartGuy you have to check whether directory exists using exists() or not and then need to call mkDirs() before saving

Comment: i did like this  is work but again save images in phone image directory
    path = getDir("FolderName", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE).getPath() + "/imageName.jpg";

Comment: I can't understand your comments and can't help you more. I have done the same thing which worked for me fine.

Comment: what i write in this line
"path/to/your/directory"

Comment: hey I got your problem, you might forgot to add permissions in Manifest file. Check it, I have added permission in answer. pass your _path string variable in place of path/to/your/directory.

Comment: "/images 
  /"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";  

my image is specific folder or i write any name for instead of this??

Comment: thnx but no new folder is create all pictures goes in phoneimage gellry

Answer (score 3):

This code is working

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected Button _button;
    protected ImageView _image;
    protected String _path;
    protected boolean _taken;

    protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN   = "photo_taken";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        _image = ( ImageView ) findViewById( R.id.imageView );
        _button = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.buttonCapture );
        _button.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) new ButtonClickHandler());

        _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
    }

    public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        public void onClick( View view ){

            Log.i("MakeMachine", "ButtonClickHandler.onClick()" );
            startCameraActivity();
        }
    }

    protected void startCameraActivity()
    {
        Log.i("MakeMachine", "startCameraActivity()" );
        File file = new File( _path );
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
        intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );

        startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        Log.i( "MakeMachine", "resultCode: " + resultCode );
        switch( resultCode )
        {
            case 0:
                Log.i( "MakeMachine", "User cancelled" );
                break;

            case -1:
                onPhotoTaken();
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void onPhotoTaken()
    {
        Log.i( "MakeMachine", "onPhotoTaken" );

        _taken = true;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( _path, options );

        _image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState( Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Log.i( "MakeMachine", "onRestoreInstanceState()");
        if( savedInstanceState.getBoolean( MainActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN ) ) {
            onPhotoTaken();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState ) {
        outState.putBoolean( MainActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken );
    }
}
```